# Lasso feature selection in r

Tags: r, feature-selection

i want to perform a lasso regression using logistic regression(my output is categorical) to select the significant variables from my dataset "data" and then to select these important variables "variables" and test them on a validationset x.test and to compare the predicted values on the real values but i got this error:
Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
  Erreur Cholmod 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' dans le fichier ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, ligne 90

```
 library(glmnet)
library(caret)
# class label must be factor 0 noevent, 1:anomalous
iris$Species<-ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa",0,1)
#data$Cardio1M=factor(data$Cardio1M)
#split data into train and test
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
data_train <- iris[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- iris[-trainIndex,]
x.train <- data.matrix (data_train [ ,1:ncol(data_train)-1])
y.train <- data.matrix (data_train$Species)
x.test <- data.matrix (data_test [,1:(ncol(data_test))-1])
y.test <- data.matrix(data_test$Species)
#fitting generalized linear modelalpha=0 then ridge regression is used, while if alpha=1 then the lasso
# of ?? values (the shrinkage coefficient)
#Associated with each value of ?? is a vector of regression coefficients. For example, the 100th value of ??, a very small one, is closer to perform least squares:
Lasso.mod <- glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha=1, nlambda=100, lambda.min.ratio=0.0001,family="binomial")
#use 10 fold cross-validation to choose optimal ??.
set.seed(1)
#cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha=1,family="binomial", nlambda=100, lambda.min.ratio=0.0001,type.measure = "class")
cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha=1,family="binomial", nlambda=100, type.measure = "class")
#Ploting the misclassification error and the diferent values of lambda
plot(cv.out)
best.lambda <- cv.out$lambda.min
best.lambda
co<-coef(cv.out, s = "lambda.min")
#Once we have the best lambda, we can use predict to obtain the coefficients.
p<-predict(Lasso.mod, s=best.lambda, type="coefficients")[1:6, ]
p
```

I want to test if the selected features contributes to reduce error on my testing set but i got error even with iris dataset

```
#Selection of the significant features(predictors)
inds<-which(co!=0)
variables<-row.names(co)[inds]
variables<-variables[!(variables %in% '(Intercept)')];
#predict output values based on selected predictors
p <- predict(cv.out, s=best.lambda, newx=x.test,type="class")
# Calculate accuracy
Accuracy<- mean(p==y.test)
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have given us any of the information needed to answer this question.

Comment: i have edited the question to specify the section where i have an error

Comment: Hello Aymen. Please read [How to Create a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and update your post. Your current question is not verifiable because you did not provide data for us to reproduce the error message you received.

Comment: ok i will try to reproduce an example on riris and return back thanks for your help

Comment: And in addtion to posting sufficient information about your data objects .... Learn to use a shift key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to leave a comment explaining what went wrong, but it was too long, so I have to post an answer. Also, I know that the following is why you get an error, but without a reproducible example, I cannot guarantee that there aren't other issues as well.

The main problem is that you're using `x.test[, variables]` instead of `x.test`. The object `cv.out` includes all the variable names, including the ones that were reduced to 0, so the `predict` command doesn't know where to find those, since you subset `x.test` to only include the variables with significant coefs.

Even if this were the case though, it still wouldn't work. The reason is that you get the significant coefs using `s = "lambda.min"`, but then you're trying to predict using `s=cv.out$lambda.1se`. The problem is that if some variable, e.g. X2, got zeroed out in the `lambda.min` model, it might still be significant in the `lambda.1se` one. So when the `predict` command tries to find it in `x.test`, it can't because it is not in `variables`.

So in the end, what you should do is:

```
p <- predict(Lasso.mod, s=best.lambda, newx=x.test, type="class")
```

There are other issues with your code too, but I don't believe they would cause error messages. I hope this helps!

#### *Major Update*

Things that you should also fix are:

- When you create `x.test` and `x.train`, change `length` to `ncol`. Actually in both cases you need `data_test [,1:(ncol(data_test))-1]`. Even though `length` and `ncol` will give you the same number in this case, they wouldn't if it was a matrix instead of a `data.frame`. Also, you need the `-1` part, because otherwise you include your `y` in your `x`.
- Change `type="response"` to `type=class"` when you create `p`, otherwise you will get an `Accuracy` of 0. (I changed it in the code above)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have tried but it didn't fix the problem i puted a reproducible example with iris dataset i hope it helps to reduce the issue

Comment: @AymenTrabelsi it turns out there were other problems with the code as well, but If you take into account the edits I made above it should work, since it does for me. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem, otherwise let me know and I will remove it.

Comment: @AymenTrabelsi, I'm very happy to help! Please consider marking it as accepted, so that it declutters the "unanswered" questions page. Thank you!

Comment: Done Thanks for collaboration